# Soundcloud likes/favorites

Tags: ajax, soundcloud

I am trying to load soundcloud likes (used to be favorites), but I am not getting any results from the ajax query.

This is the url I am trying to load: http://soundcloud.com/gazebo-fm/likes

```
function soundCloudTrackData(linkUrl) {
    var url = soundCloudApiUrl(linkUrl, soundcloudApiKey);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false
    }).done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Soundcloud process error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
    });

}

function soundCloudApiUrl(url, soundcloudApiKey) {
    var useSandBox = false;
    var domain = useSandBox ? 'sandbox-soundcloud.com' : 'soundcloud.com'
    return (/api\./.test(url) ? url + '?' : 'http://api.' + domain +'/resolve?url=' + url + '&') + 'format=json&consumer_key=' + apiKey +'&callback=?';
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the url to `http://soundcloud.com/gazebo-fm/favorites`

`/likes` is used in new soundcloud's api, which is not yet documented.

Comment: Besides it's not fully functional yet. For example `http://m.soundcloud.com/gazebo-fm/likes` whereas `http://m.soundcloud.com/gazebo-fm/favorites` wouldn't. This is for mobile version but there may be such inconsistencies in desktop version as well.

Comment: yes. they are so far away to complete desktop version still. mobile, well. maybe in 2015 :)

Comment: if you want to go under the hood of the new soundcloud, open dev tools on chrome for example, and check the network tab
you can see that new call for likes is: https://api.soundcloud.com/e1/users/USER_ID/likes?format=json&client_id=CLIENT_ID&limit=50&linked_partitioning=1&offset=OFFSET&order=favorited_at